# Ubuntu not detecting external monitor connected via USB-C dock

Tags: 16.04, usb, multiple-monitors, display, external-monitor

Working with Ubuntu 16.04.

I have an HP USB-C dock ([https://www.amazon.com/HP-Elite-USB-Docking-Station/dp/B01BBXPKEK](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01BBXPKEK)) that I use with my work laptop. I have a wireless keyboard, mouse, ethernet, power, and two external monitors connected through it.

Using Windows, everything works perfectly fine. Using Ubuntu, everything works except for the monitors, which are connected through HDMI. They don't show up in the display settings at all.

The monitors work if I connect them straight to the laptpop's USB-C port through a USB-C - DVI adapter. However, I don't have enough ports on this laptop for that to be a viable solution.

Any idea what I could do to remedy this?

EDIT:

Here is the output when I run `xrandr`...

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 2160, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 276mm x 155mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.93    48.04  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96  
DP-2 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 521mm x 293mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1920x1080_60.00  59.96
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I think this is a driver issue. Since its proprietary, you'd best ask the manufacturer,  HP,  about it, but I think you might be out of luck since [somebody else has already asked](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Video-Display-and-Touch/Linux-drivers-for-Elite-USB-C-dock/td-p/5614508) this question on their product forums.

Comment: Oh jeez, that's a bummer. Good ol' HP I suppose.

Comment: You could try again with HP, but again, this is very hardware-specific.